# Local Notification while in an inactive application state

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification, uiapplication

I am not sure if this is not possible or if I am implementing it wrong.

I am trying to complete a task in the background using `beginBackgroundTask`(`expirationHandler`) and then post a `LocalNotification` once it is complete on `iOS10`. The issue is that the `Notification` will not consistently fire - I can set a `breakpoint` to see it scheduled using `presentLocalNotificationNow` but it does not always display to the user and only once the app comes back to the `foreground` (by opening it from the home screen) does `didReceiveLocalNotification` get called.

If I check the application state when I am scheduling the notification it has a rawValue of 2 which I believe is inactive so I'm assuming that is the reason it is not delivering the notification to the user.

I've tried scheduling the `notification` for 5 secs after the completion of the task and then calling `endBackgroundTask` immediately but the notification still doesn't consistently show to the user. `EndBackgroundTask` does get called which I would assume should move the application to the background from inactive at which point the `notification` should show but I'm assuming it is not immediate and at the system's discretion when that actually happens.

What am I doing wrong?

The relevant code is:

```
let task = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: nil)  
// Long running task  
let notification = UILocalNotification()  
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName  
notification.alertBody = "Message"  
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .sound], categories: nil)  
UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)  
UIApplication.shared.presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)  
UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(task)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can tell, the issue was due to presentLocalNotificationNow being async and returning immediately so there wasn't enough time for the system to register the notification. I solved the issue by scheduling the notification earlier so there was enough time.